# Scroll to Top after Adding Product to Cart?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, product-page

I'd like the user to be scrolled to the top of the product page upon successfully adding a product to their cart, so that they can see the success message.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code in your custom js

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
    $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function (event) {    
        $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentUpdated', function ()  {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: This causes the animation to fire off N number of times (number of items in the minicart) which can cause page stuttering if someone has 3+ items in the cart.  (And it gets worse with more items 7+ in the cart).

Answer (score 0):

Extend the core Magento_Catalog view and put this at the bottom inside Magento_Catalog->product->view->form.phtml:

```
    <script>
  require([
    'jquery'
  ], function($) {
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      $("#product_addtocart_form").on('submit', function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, "slow");
      });

    });
  })
</script>
```